# multi series chart with non-repeating colors and strokes

Tags: altair

I have a Pandas dataframe of three columns: *date*, *price* and *symbol*.
The *symbol* column has many rows of 20 different values (categories). I'm trying to create a line chart where each of those categories will be a different line of a different color. The x axis is *date* and y axis is *price*.

As there are so many different values on the *symbol* column, when I try to chart them I get lines with repeated colors. I thought that I could use *strokeDash* to fix the issue, but on each color repetition I get the same type of dash, so I'm unable to differentiate them.

Is there a way in which I can, for example, resort the types of dashes in a different order so that the next time I get the same color I get a different dash?

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
x='date',
y='price',
color='symbol',
strokeDash='symbol')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to distinguish 20 different values, it may make more sense to use a color scale that has 20 different values. Taking a look at the list of supported [vega color schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/) documentation, `category20` seems like a good option. Here is a quick example of using it:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

rng = np.random.RandomState(1701)

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': np.tile(np.arange(10), 20),
    'price': rng.randn(20, 10).cumsum(1).ravel(),
    'symbol': np.repeat(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'), 10)
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
  x='date',
  y='price',
  color=alt.Color('symbol', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20')),
)
```

[image]